# NTP Unexpected origin timestamp

Tags: linux-mint, ntp, ntpd

I can't start NTP service, so the time of the machine is wrong.

```
Mar 14 11:36:25 ntpd[27956]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xe2174e4d.523af1e4 does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@66.228.58.20 xmt 0xe2172
Mar 14 11:36:25 ntpd[27956]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xe2174e4d.55e58e52 does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@199.188.64.12 xmt 0xe217
Mar 14 14:36:36 systemd[1]: ntp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Mar 14 14:36:36 systemd[1]: ntp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

> OS: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia
>
> NTP version: 1:4.2.8p10+dfsg-5ubuntu7.1

Comment: Do you have the latest NTP package installed?

Comment: Yes is the latest package

Comment: The ntp.service options are read from /etc/default/ntp

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your ntp service isn't loading ***because*** your server time is wrong.
Try this: stop the service and start it again with the "-qg" options.

```
ntpd -qg
```

After that, start ntp again and see if this solve your problem.
Keep watching it for a few days; if it gets unsync again, you may have a more complex problem.